# can you use jquery lazyload on all images (not just ones out of view)

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

i have a webpage with a lot of images (photo album).  I am using [lazyloading jquery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) which is great to only load the images out of browser view when i scroll down.

The one issue i have is that i want the loading icon to show up first on images loading IN the current view as well as some of them are big images and they show up with that bad browser "image not loaded yet" icon until they download.   I don't see any property on this plugin to support this for both in view and for scrolling.

does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been playing with the plugin in my own webpage.
In plugin description there is also the timeout function that is actually the behaviour you want.

Check the demo page at http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_timeout.html

If you need further help, please comment.

Comment: looking at your website i noticed that on refreshing your reloading the images instead of loading it from the browser cache which is f***ed up. I dont really see the point of using lazy loading if the images are not cached..

Answer (score 0):

The demo page of [link text](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)lazyloading jquery plugin doesn't wprk in FF3.6.

You can check out this plugin called [JAIL](http://www.sebarmeli.com/projects/jail) that works perfectly (there are few examples). I suggest to keep the Net tab of Firebug open when you open the examples pages.